# Microsoft Graph API Application Collections

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

In the Azure portal, under "Enterprise Applications" there is a "Collections" view where applications can be grouped into collections.

Are there any actions for managing these collections available via the Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: hello @Jack,  any update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to add collections in enterprise application programmatically using Graph API or any other method . Unfortunately , there are no possible ways available which can be used except for adding them from portal.

You can create a feedback for it from Portal (as shown in below image) or feature request on [Microsoft Graph support](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/support).

[image]